# Angular File Structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 users: admin and super admin. And both of them have same menu but different content.

Any idea what the best approach to make their view?. Right now i'm using ng-hide and check for his id. But more content will be messy.

Is there a good way to make it less messy and better approach?

Comment: You can create a separate partial view for each and conditionally use `ng-include` to use one or another, or use `ng-show`/`ng-if` like you have been doing.

Comment: yeah, looks like i'm going with ng-include. it make more structural.

Answer (score 1):

The clean code way: Just because the menu is different you should not make an angular controller for each role.

You should create a object, which provides the menue items for every user. The angular part should be just rendering the information provided by the other object.

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical issue, that you have to solve on the server side, but if you want to do it on the frontend, I would suggest to get the menu from server, with properly set right properties.

Your model will get it and store it in your model, something like:

```
$http.get('http://rest-server/menu')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.my.menu;
});
```

The menu will provide the content (click on a menu item -> get allowed services from a defined REST-API) for the certain user (admin/superadmin/whatever).

If you want to implement it completely at the frontend, someone with technical background can easly override your rules.

EDIT: If it is going only about showable content you can use `ng-if`, `ng-show`,  `ng-hide`, there are plenty of examples at stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry but it's not the menu, but the content. the menu is identical so i'm not using api. Thanks